# URL call fails in viewDidAppear of Initial View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am making a URL call to server in viewDidAppear of the Initial View Controller .If that server call succeeds ( server sends response code 1) then only the user can access the app, else he is asked to retry. Even though Internet is connected, around 2 on 10 times that first url call fails with response nil (have set **timeoutInterval to 7 seconds**).
    I tested the same URL call with Chrome Postman Plugin. But it is responding on every request.What could be the reason ? It happens sometime, so it not reproducible also.Below is my code of AppDelegate

```
//Setting up NSURL Cache
NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024
                                                     diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                         diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];

//Setting up AWS Thing
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider=[[AWSStaticCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:k_AmazonKeyID secretKey:k_AmazonPassword];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

//Setting up for RateApp thing
[Appirater setAppId:@"********"];
[Appirater setDebug:YES];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
return YES;
```

and below code is of method in viewDidAppear where I am calling the URL

```
+(void)callURLWithString:(NSString*)urlStr withBody:(NSDictionary*)dict andIsMethodPOST:(BOOL)isPOST withBlock:(void(^)(NSData *data,NSError *error))block
{
NSString *body=[HelperMethods_SuperdocPatientsAPI     makeParamtersString:dwithEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url;
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
NSURLRequestCachePolicy policy;

if (isPOST) {
    //Post method
    url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url     cachePolicy:poltimeoutInterval:k_URLTimeoutSeconds];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
else
{
    //Get method
    url= [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",urlStr,body]];
    request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url     cachePolicy:poltimeoutInterval:k_URLTimeoutSeconds];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request addValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
}

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error;

NSData *outputReceived=[NSURLConnection     sendSynchronousRequest:requreturningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (response == nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Please Check YInternet     Connection and Try Again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"otherButtonTitles:nil]    show];
    });
    NSLog("%@",error.description);
    block(nil,error);
}
else
{
    block(outputReceived,nil);
}
}
```

Will use of AFNetworking Library solve my problem?

Comment: i think you problem not relate where did you call your request ! you should review your request !

Comment: Request as some some properties am I setting wrong. can you please elaborate your solution ?

Comment: mm , sorry , you should w8 or chat later